# Laravel Cannot use Token of user that has been Soft-Delete

Tags: laravel

The token generated by soft-deleted user not working, Is there any way to use the token of soft-deleted users ?

Comment: show lines of code which not working

Comment: the scenario i have is i login my user account that has been soft delete, the return of my user model have a token and information, i use that token to bypass the middleware but its not working because of token is unthenticated.

Comment: so you want users that are soft deleted, can login and use your application without any problem?

Comment: yeah exactly. but the token generated when i am login is unthenticated because of i use soft deleted user. i try to use other user that not been soft delete and the token is working ..

Comment: are you using native laravel authentication, or jwt based auth?

Comment: Im currently use laravel passport token

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the user that has been softDeleted. You must use the withTrashed method. So if you want to find the softDeleted user with a token you must write something like this code below:

```
$user = User::whereToken($token)->withTrashed()->first();
```